# Tkinter opens instantly subprocess instead of waiting for button click

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a code editor based on nano. I've decided to make GUI for it, and the GUI language I chose is Python. I'm trying to make a button that opens batch files on Tkinter. I did so by importing **import subprocess**. Now, I created a button that opens the batch file with subprocess:
`ttk.Button(frm, text="New Session", command=subprocess.run(['csession.bat']) ).grid(column=0, row=1)`

Little problem is, when I launch the file, the subprocess action instantly gets executed instead of waiting for the user to click. I'm using VSCode and also debugging in VSCode (if that does any difference).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use lambda if you want to define the command this way.
you can also create a function and set the command to run it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import subprocess

def runBat():
    subprocess.run(['foo.bat'])

root = tk.Tk()

ttk.Button(root,text="text",command= lambda: subprocess.run(['foo.bat'])).pack()
ttk.Button(root,text="text2",command=runBat).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried it and now it's working as desired.